# How to manually create an Outlook signature with images?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I have developed a desktop application that has a feature to create an Outlook signature.

*This works perfectly, for the most part. The application generates the HTML signature and saves it in the correct location and Outlook is able to see it just fine for use in outgoing emails.*

The issue is with images. Is it possible to somehow specify a local `.png` file, for example, to be included in the signature?

Within the HTML my application generates, I include the following `<img>` tag:

```
<img width=152 height=84 src="[path]\image.png">
```

This **works** just fine on our **local** systems. When starting an outgoing email, the image appears as it should. The recipient, however, gets the usual "missing image" red X in place of the intended image.

**Edit**

Due to firewall restrictions, linking to an online image is not available in this case.

Also, Outlook allows us to add offline images directly using its own signature editor, so I am I am hoping to mimic that ability.

Comment: You may try placing your signature image on the Internet and edit the HTML to the internet path to see the result.

Comment: Have you tried base64 encoding your image and then doing something like `<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgA..."/>`?

Comment: I found the reference about using offline images with the sig editor (https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/outlook/1299-outlook-add-image-signature.html) which leads to a question. Are you able to view the resulting signature from this "solution" in HTML to see how it's done?

Comment: @fred_dot_u Yes. Microsoft adds dozens of lines of additional code to even just a simple text signature, much of which I don't understand. But i tried to mimic the same file structure and img tags. There must be something in there I'm missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Outlook since version 2013 no longer embeds images in signatures and maintains
the link to the location of the picture, although a reference to a local image
will not exist for the recipient.

The issue only happens when you’ve manually created the signature in an HTML editor
rather than by using the Outlook Signature Editor.

This works when including the picture via the Outlook Signature Editor,
because special HTML tags are used, which are recognized
upon sending, so that Outlook will still end up embedding these linked pictures.
These tags come from the old
[Vector Markup Language (VML)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_Markup_Language),
which is still used today by Outlook.

You could use the
[Outlook Signature Editor](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-and-add-a-signature-to-messages-8ee5d4f4-68fd-464a-a1c1-0e1c80bb27f2)
to create an example signature for seeing the VML tag `<v:image>` in action,
then modifying your HTML accordingly.

One resource by Microsoft is the article
[Using the Image Element](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/vml/web-workshop---how-to-use-vml-on-web-pages-----image--element).
The following example comes from the article:

```
<v:image style='width:100pt;height:80pt' src="image1.jpg" />
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have tried using the `<v>` tag instead of `<img>` and the image will display locally on outgoing messages, but is "missing" for the recipient. So it is still an issue. I've looked through the massive formats generated when using the Outlook Signature Editor, which DOES embed the image in outgoing messages, but I cannot make sense of how that works.

Comment: Post the signature code if you wish me to have a look.

Comment: Thank you. You definitely lead me in the right direction. I needed to keep a lot of the code that Outlook generates and include it in my own template, but it's now working perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you don't need to do something special with your signature.htm file. Just enable the hidden Outlook option described in the [Microsoft Support Article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2779191/). Or you can use the [free Outlook Tweaker](https://www.outlookfreeware.com/en/products/all/ReliefJetTweakerOutlook) to enable this option (I'm one of the developers of the Tweaker).

Comment: This does look promising but unfortunately our clients do not have admin rights on their computers so modifying the registry is not an option either.

Comment: From what I've found, editing the registry is going to be the only option. This link explains a bit more detail: https://www.msoutlook.info/question/signature-images-not-sending-or-visible-for-receiver

Comment: If you could expand on your answer to explain a registry edit is needed, I'll accept it. Also, I assume your tweaker software would require admin rights to make the change?

Comment: @Zephyr, our Outlook Tweaker doesn't require admin rights.

Answer (score 0):

Just as superuser requires that one upload an image or provide a URL to display an image in a post, your application must also make similar allocations.

As Steve Fan suggests, you have to have an external resource that Outlook can access. A possible exception would be if you have an in-house server that is accessible by outside users.

Replace the [path] with the URL of the image and the intended objective will function. An exception to this would be if the recipients have their email client block outside images for inbox messages, which is common and cannot be bypassed.

Comment: Thank you. This, unfortunately, will not work for my case. I've updated my original question.